# Explanation for filling a dictionary with user input

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

Could I get an explanation for the line of code `responses[name] = response`? I dont really understand how that line stores the user input in a dictionary. (This is an exercise for the Python crash course book if that's why the code looks odd.)

```
responses = {}

# Set a flag to indicate that polling is active
polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    # Prompt for the person's name and response
    name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
    response = input("Which mountain would you climb one day? ")

    # Store the responses in a dictionary
    responses[name] = response

    #Find out if anyone else is going to take the poll
    repeat = input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes / no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_active = False

# polling is complete, show the results
print("\n --- Poll results --- ")
for name, response in responses.items():
    print(f"{name.title()} would like to climb {response.title()}")
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're confused about. That's just the syntax for setting a dictionary element. If you're not sure about that, perhaps you need to read some more.

Comment: What's not to get? It's assigning the key `name` to the value `response` in the dict `responses`. Have you not learned about dicts? If not, you could look at the [official Python tutorial on them](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

`responses` is the dictionary. When you loop through the `while` loop, the `name` is getting stored as the key in the dictionary and the `response` is getting stored as the value.  So basically this

```
responses[name] = response
```

is saying, take the `name` that is given, store it as the key, and take the `response` and store it as the value, each iteration through the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now

Comment: Wait so if the input for name was john and mountain was Everest, would it store john as the key and response as the value, in the responses dictionary?

Comment: @Arekusandaa Yes, that is correct. You can open up a python interpreter, and initialize an empty dictionary and experiment with the code there. Copy/paste  this into your interpreter: `d = {}; name = "Jacob"; response = "Eyjafjällajökull"; d[name] = response ; print(d)`. That might explain a bit more of how it works.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Yes, that explains it a lot better. So in the example you created there, does it create a dictionary called d, a string called jacob and a string called Eyjafjällajökull. Then would it put Jacob as the key in the dictionary d, and Eyjafjällajökull as the value. Then would it print {'Jacob' : 'Eyjafjällajökull'}. If so, then thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in themselves are a way to assign a key to an item then be able to look up items using those keys. In simple terms it would be like an address to an house. The address is the identifier to the house.

Lets look at some code to break down `responses[name] = response`

Starting with an empty dictionary

`responses = {}`

looking at the keys in the dictionary

`responses.keys()`

> dict_keys([])

We can see there are no keys (or addresses from the earlier example) because it return and empty list `[]`

How do you add a key to dictionary that already exists? One option is to add it using the bracket syntax.

In this example we will add the key (or address) `'123 main street'` which is a string with the value of `'Our Nice Private Home'` which is also a string.

`responses['123 main street'] = 'Our Nice Private Home'`

Now what do the keys look like?

`responses.keys()`

> dict_keys(['123 main street'])

You can see the key '123 main street' was added to the dictionary.

In your example `responses[name] = response`

`responses` is the dictionary, `name` contains what the user entered after the prompt `What is your name?` and `response` contains what the user entered after the prompt `Which mountain would you climb one day?`

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! I think I just had a brain fart and didnt understand it for a second lol. So if the input for name is John and response is Everest would the Key be 'John' and the value 'Everest'. Then at the last line would it print John would like to climb Everest? If so then thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly! They are doing some tricky tuple unpacking when calling `for name, response in responses.items():` but it sounds like you understand that part. If that is greek. I suggest googling "python tuple unpacking". you'll find some great resources that can explain tuple unpacking too.

Comment: Thanks! The example doesn't say anything about tuple unpacking (probably because that's too advanced) but I understand the example now. I did know about the whole getting a key value pair using .items() but I think the example and the Syntax was what confused me. In the end, we got there though, thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome. I would not worry about tuple unpacking until they get to it. I’m glad I could help though!